# Showing plane and line are parallel

Tags: vectors

I am working on "Determine the values of $k$ for which the plane $(2k-1)x-ky+z=5+k$ and the line $x/2=ky=k-z$ are parallel."

I understand how to get the solutions of $k=0$ or $k=1$ using the dot product of the normal vector to the plane and the direction vector of the line.

My trouble is verifying $k=0$ as a solution. Upon substituting $k=0$ in the two equations, I get $-x+z-5$ and $x/2=-z$.

How do I show the particular plane and line are parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not substitute $k=0$, because equation of line in standard form $$\displaystyle \frac{x-0}{2} = \frac{y-0}{\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{z-k}{-1}\;,$$ Where $k\neq 0$

$\bf{Solution::}$

If plane and line are parallel, Then plane and normal vector are perpendicular.

So Dot product of $<2k-1,-k,1>$ and $\displaystyle <2,\frac{1}{k},-1>$ are zero.

So $\displaystyle (2k-1)\cdot 2+(-k)\cdot \frac{1}{k}+(1)\cdot (-1) =0$

So $2k-1-1 =0\Rightarrow k=1$

Comment: Hmmm. That's what I first did when I tried the problem. OK, the answers given in the book I'm looking at must have a mistake.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the line and the normal vector of the plane are perpendicular, instead of "plane and normal vector are perpendicular"? Just a small thing.